# What is Chassis ID LED on motherboard?

Tags: computer-building

I'm a little confused about the purpose of the ID LED (Chassis ID LED, page 99 in [the manual for the S5520UR motherboard](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5520ur/sb/e44031012_s5520ur_s5520urt_tps_r1_9.pdf)). The manual states this about the ID LED:

> The chassis ID LED provides a visual indication of a system being
>   serviced. The state of the chassis ID LED is affected by the
>   following:
>
> - Toggled by the chassis ID button
> - Controlled by the Chassis Identify command (IPMI)
> - Controlled by the Chassis Identify LED command (OEM)

And that a 1Hz blink for the ID LED means that the state of the system is "Identify active via command." I don't understand what this means and I haven't been able to find anything online about "ID LEDs."

*(Original question edited because more than one question being asked.)*

Comment: You purchased this motherboard new or used?  Intel has not sold it's own motherboard for nearly a decade is the reason I asked.

Comment: @Ramhound I bought it (and most of my parts) off of Ebay, and the listing states it was recently pulled from a working server and is tested to work. I'm contacting the seller now to see if (s)he also had this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chassis ID light is there to make it easy for you to identify which of the many server boards in a rack is the server you want to find. You mash the button, go around to the back of the rack, and the blinking light shows which is the server you want.

PS: Multiple questions within a question [are problematic](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Please limit the scope of what you ask for, by posing one issue per question. It's OK to make multiple posts on a project such as this, and editing this question down lets you close this out now you've got the answer, and move on.

Comment: Thank you for your advice -- this answered one of the questions (what is the ID LED) very well. I'll edit this question to only be about that question, and move the other half of the question (why is my second CPU not working?) to a new question.