# Second Xeon CPU fails in Intel S5520UR server motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building, xeon

I'm building my first PC and chose cheap old server bits, an Intel [S5520UR](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36456/intel-server-board-s5520ur.html) server motherboard [TPS manual here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36456/intel-server-board-s5520ur.html) and a pair of (matched) [Xeon X5570](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37111/intel-xeon-processor-x5570-8m-cache-2-93-ghz-6-40-gt-s-intel-qpi.html)s.

One CPU works fine, with no errors on boot. However, when adding in the second CPU, the ID LED begins solid green, and after a few seconds blinks amber and the fans increase their speed (4-pin PWM fans). (With one CPU, it also starts solid green and blinks amber after a few seconds, but it is accompanied by the monitor turning on and a series of POST LED progress codes, and the fans do not turn at a higher RPM).

(Note: That ID LED is not indicative of anything, so I'm unsure if this is useful. (It is used for [finding a server computer in a chassis](https://superuser.com/questions/1460132/what-is-chassis-id-led-on-motherboard).))

Page 97 of the [TPS manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5520ur/sb/e44031012_s5520ur_s5520urt_tps_r1_9.pdf) describes the system status LED, which lies right next to the ID LED on the motherboard. This LED only flashes blue when AC power is connected and disconnected. It's possible that I misidentified the status LED as the ID LED -- this would contradict the placement of the LEDs in the diagram below but make sense because the status LED is bicolor green/amber and is always on. You can see the below diagram from the manual (page 124) and watch the videos below to see why I am confused.

[image: diagnostic LED positions]

With two CPUs, it has an amber 1Hz blink, which corresponds to a few possible non-fatal errors for the status LED:

> Non-fatal alarm – system is likely to fail:
>
> BIOS Detected
>
> 1. In non-mirroring mode, if the threshold of ten correctable errors is crossed within the window
> 2. PCI Express* uncorrectable link errors.
>
> Integrated BMC Detected
>
> 3. Critical threshold crossed – Voltage, temperature, power nozzle, power gauge, and PROCHOT (therm Ctrl) sensors.
> 4. VRD Hot asserted.
> 5. Minimum number of fans to cool the system are not present or have failed.

If any of these were the problem, how would I be able to diagnose them? No PCIe devices are plugged in to the motherboard, and this happens right after the system turns on (so it's unlikely that voltage or temperature is exceeding its limits). As for the last possibility, one fan (just the CPU 1 fan) was enough to boot when only one processor was in; now I have two CPU fans plugged in (and I've tried plugging in case fans into the memory and system fan headers) to no avail.

Here are some videos. In both, the minimum RAM config (1 DIMM in A1) is used, but (as mentioned in the notes below) I don't believe RAM is part of the problem.

- One CPU, boots fine (note that the 3 quick beeps do not indicate a memory error: the diagnostic beeps for memory error are 3 longer beeps): [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n_bD-tN9kDbvqF3nJ7GJyq4hzUZ9HL8D/view?usp=sharing)
- Two CPUs, no boot. Note the fans getting louder right after the ID LED starts to blink. [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYtsko1V8BigUbtBwzBStUqrmMCDS1yl/view?usp=sharing)

Other places I've looked:

- [Intel forums search for 'S5520UR'](https://forums.intel.com/s/global-search/s5520ur?language=en_US), but I haven't been able to find this issue.
- [This post](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/Poweredge-1500SC-won-t-boot-with-second-CPU-installed-EVEN-WITH/td-p/2297277) seems to be about a similar issue (CPU fans at higher RPM than normal, problem only with two processors) and mentions a possible issue with VRM, but the results seem inconclusive. (I also don't have a clue how to replace/add a VRM.)

Other things to note:

- None of the diagnostic POST LEDs are lit with two CPUs in (which indicates that the problem is likely happening before any of the POST progress codes).
- The monitor is not detecting a signal from the motherboard with two CPUs in.
- The CPUs should be matched, so that shouldn't be the problem.
- Each CPU works when used as the lone CPU in socket 1.
- I'm (pretty) sure that the RAM is not the problem, as I've tried multiple configurations and the RAM all seem to work when used with processor 1. (However, the C channel on the motherboard seems to be fried, but that is for processor 1 and the computer's worked fine without using that channel: could this be the cause of the issue?)

I'm not at all experienced with computer debugging, so any kind of pointers / requests for more information are helpful. I don't know if there are any telltale signs any problems, like if the second socket is bad (if it is, how could I test this?).

*(Question narrowed from original question which also asked about ID LED)*

Comment: Your troubleshooting methodology so far has been excellent. When this happens in my shop, it's most likely a foreign object in the CPU 2 socket. Put a bright light on it and look for dust, dirt, lint, or other obstructions. Blow across the socket with compressed gas (not directly into it, which can shove an object further in). Do the same with the "C" memory sockets. If that does not resolve it, with the errors you describe, that's a sick motherboard.